# Need to remove everything after # in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you visit my site at http://joshoak.es/test you'll see that the URL changes to "http://joshoak.es/test/#/screens/d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724"

I can see in the document where that comes from

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){jimMain.init("screens/d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724");});
```

If I remove that code, the page doesn't load. This isn't my site, so I don't know a lot about the structure, but a friend asked me if I could fix this. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I've realized that the way the website is developed, it will not allow the page to load without all that information after it. It was built using a mobile development platform.

Comment: That's because it's the old way React-Router and friends behaved (including people jumping on the band wagon with their own code), abusing the FragmentID syntax to fake a "real" URL. Your browser loads the page on the base location, that loads a JS "app" that then reads the bit after the `#/` and renders whatever "page" that should be. It was a terrible idea at the time because it broke URLs, it's still a terrible idea today because it breaks URLs, and thankfully no framework today does this anymore (by default, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
```

Comment: @chrx Due to the lack of proper browser support, this option isn't recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "http://joshoak.es/test/#/screens/d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724"
result = url.split('#')[0];
window.location.href=result;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This puts me into a constant redirect loop between http://joshoak.es/test/#/screens/d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724 and http://joshoak.es/test/ and the page never loads

Comment: What do you want to load actually?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(window.location.href.split('?')[0])
newWindowLocationHREF = window.location.href.split('?')[0]
window.location.href = newWindowLocationHREF
```